# How to remove the margin from div

Tags: html, css

I'm making a model of a website in HTML and Css and I do not know how to remove this little space on my div element

[image]

I've tried to put padding and margin to 0 but nothing happens

Here's my CSS code

```
body{
    padding-left:269px;
    padding-right:269px;
    background-color:black;
    margin: 0; 
}

.blanco{
    background-color: #fff;
    height:780px;
    width: 1366px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

The div element is named "blanco"

The arrows are a CSS too
Here's the HTML:

```
  <div class="setaEsquerda">
        <img src="images/Path Copy.svg" alt="">
      </div> 
      <div class="setaDireita">
        <img src="images/Path.svg" alt="">
      </div>
```

and here's the css

```
.setaEsquerda{
    position: absolute;
    top: 42.1%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}

.setaDireita{
    position: absolute;
    top: 42.1%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 1290px;
}
```

Comment: Please include an [example].

Comment: You also set a padding to your body so if blanco is a child of your body this padding will be applied leaving `269px` left and right black as your background color is black.

Comment: Yes but the problem is not with the black bars, is the tiny bar close to the cards

Comment: Can you please provide a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) with the minimal HTML and CSS to reproduce this. Because it is a guessing game otherwise.

Comment: here https://liveweave.com/m4BYaL but the thing is there are a lot of images that are not gonna show up

Comment: There's no need to use exactly your website for it, quite the opposite actually. The [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be the smallest possible bit of code that correctly represents the problem you are having without code that certainly is not relevant to the problem. Use some [dummy images](https://loremipsum.io/21-of-the-best-placeholder-image-generators/) if necessary. They do not necessarily need to be sharp or have the right aspect ratio as long as that is not part of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifing the size of your div.blanco .. Any bigger screen than that will also show the `<body>` behind it, if .blanco ends there.

Answer (score 0):

I am just assuming and i think the issue you have may be because of these arrows. They are pushing the other content down.

[image]

You may want to divide the body into 3 section, then apply the style you want and it should be affective

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left-col">arrow left</div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Some text</h1>
      <button>Hey</button>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">arrow right</div>
  </div>
</body>

<style>
  .main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: the arrows are an image with css too, I edit the answer so you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

try not to give a size for your Blanco Class in your CSS code.

```
.blanco{
background-color: #fff;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).